# how to insert records into a table with Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, append, sql-insert

I am using zf2 and Doctrine for a project I am developing, and I need to create a function that takes all of the records from a `SELECT` query and inserts or appends them into another table (or entity).  The [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#constructing-a-new-querybuilder-object) says that QueryBuilder only offers `SELECT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` functionality, and I remember reading somewhere that `INSERT` and `APPEND` are not included because Doctrine doesn't want to lose control of related records that might go missing by only updating one table that has relationships with others.

How can I use Doctrine to add a group of records to a table?

Answer (score 2):

You can create enities from records and push them to db:

```php
foreach ( $records as $record ) {
    $someEntity = new SomeTable();

    $someEntity->setName($record['name']);
    $someEntity->setFoo($record['bar']);

    $em->persist($someEntity);
}

$em->flush();
```